# How can I select recent year data for each id in MySQL database table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL DBMS and want to select recent year data from the table. (Excluding past year data)

For instance, I have following database.

```
cYear, wId, wSalary
2015, 1111, 250
2014, 1111, 270
2015, 2222, 350
2014, 3333, 400
2013, 3333, 230
2013, 4444, 350
```

For the person who has wId=1111, I want to exclude data where cYear=2014. Also, exclude data where cYear=2013 for the person who has wId=3333.

So, I would like to get

```
cYear, wId, wSalary
2015, 1111, 250
2015, 2222, 350
2014, 3333, 400
2013, 4444, 350
```

I am thinking that I can use group by and MAX(cYear). So, I created following query.

```
SELECT cYear, wId, wSalary FROM table WHERE cYear in (SELECT MAX(cYear) FROM table GROUP BY wId)
```

But, I still get all data.

Which query I have to use to get recent year dataset?

Thanks

Comment: What if there are two or more records with the same max year?

Comment: the record must one record for each uinque wId in each year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to get one records per wId for max year-

```
SELECT 
    wId, cYear, wSalary
FROM
    (SELECT 
        t1.*, @rn:=IF(@wId = wId, @rn + 1, IF(@wId:=wId, 1, 1)) rn
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        your_table
    ORDER BY wId , cYear) t1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @wId:=- 1, @rn:=0) t2) t
WHERE
    rn = 1;
```

If your data has combination of wId and cYear unique, then below should also work.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM your_table t1
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT wId, MAX(cYear) cYear FROM your_table GROUP BY wId
  ) t2
ON t1.wId    = t2.wId
AND t1.cYear = t2.cYear;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do using Procedure in sql.
Here **tblDemo** is your table

```
Create proc usp_demo
as
begin 

create table #tblTemp(pkid int primary key identity,cYear nvarchar(15), wId nvarchar(15), wSalary nvarchar(15))

create table #tblEmpList(pkid int primary key identity,wId nvarchar(15))  -- for unique wId

insert into #tblEmpList select distinct(wId) from tblDemo

--select * from #tblEmpList

DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @numrows int
DECLARE @employee_id nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @maxYear bigint


SET @i = 1
SET @numrows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tblEmpList)
IF @numrows > 0
    WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(pkid) FROM #tblEmpList))
    BEGIN


        -- get the next employee primary key
        SET @employee_id = (SELECT wId FROM #tblEmpList WHERE pkid = @i)
        set @maxYear=(SELECT max(cYear) FROM tblDemo WHERE wId = @employee_id)

insert into #tblTemp select cYear , wId , wSalary from tblDemo where cYear=@maxYear and wId=@employee_id

        -- increment counter for next employee
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END


select * from #tblTemp
drop table #tblTemp

end

exec usp_demo
```

> And the output is which you requried

Answer (score 0):

**try with short query**

```
select * from de group by wId order by cYear desc,wId asc;
```

[check here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32800/1)